# How to parse date of this format

Tags: swift, date, parsing

Im working with API which has this kind of date format: `/Date(1538744710756+0200)/`. Looks like it's numer of seconds since 1970 + timezone. Is this some known format? Maybe there is some built in way to convert it to `Swift` `Date`? I know how to do this by extracting values from string, but maybe there is some built in mechanism.

Comment: Using this initializer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780353-init should give you the date if you pass the number as `Int` / 1000. That date gave me `2018-10-05 13:05:10 +0000`

Comment: [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)